# iOS11 Safari/HTML5 Audio Capture?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, audio, recorder.js

iOS11 apparently implemented `getUserMedia`.  Finally!  As such, I am trying to record audio (only) via [recorder.js](http://xepoch.com/code/recorder.js) (well-known lib) in Safari on iOS.  This works (of course) on Chrome/Android.

The `Blob` object returned from any recording has zero-length.  iOS now properly asks for permission to the microphone and I can start recording. 
 There are no errors, no null references, just simply any recording is a zero-length array.  *Is this a known bug?*

Is there a mechanism or workaround in this to properly capture any raw PCM audio?